# underlined element but not showing text-decoration at web-kit-anylink (user agent stylesheet) at Elements?

Tags: css

I am newbie with javascript and trying to code a very simple page.

I meet this problem. As you can see in this picture, I code some elements named Home, Bane, Tour, Contact, More and all of them have underline.

As tutorial, they must have text-decoration at something called web-kit-anylink in user agent stylesheet.

But as you can see in this picture [picture about this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYiGG.png), when I click to Home for example, the user agent style sheet show only body, not more.

I just want to change the text-decoration from underline to another one. But at first, I want to show it in the Styles of the Elements .

Could you please help me in this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can step down through the children of an element by clicking on the right-facing arrow next to it. In your image there is a black right facing arrow next to div, click on that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you clicked on the `body`, not on the `a` element.

If you select an `a` element, you can see the [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) on Styles Panel.

To do that, simply click on the button I showed with the arrow, and then click on `Home` link.

[image]